# Need help with a trigonometry proof: $\sin{(90-\theta)}=\cos{\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

I know that $\sin{(90-\theta)}=\cos{\theta}$.

I have looked up every where for the proof where it is done using co-ordinate geometry which I am finding difficulty to understand. Can anyone please explain it to me or show an easier alternative proof?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What are your definitions of sine and cosine?

Comment: go by the definitions :)

Comment: "cosine" means "sine of the compliment". What is the compliment of $\theta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the formula $\sin(A-B)=\sin A \cdot \cos B-\cos A \cdot \sin B,$ so $$\sin(90-\theta)=\sin90\cos\theta-\cos90\sin\theta \implies \cos\theta.$$